# Equal size 'table' frames and deleting a single frame

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a 'table' in Tkinter but as a separate function linked to an OptionMenu, I have created another frame which needs to be added/removed depending on the choice. My code is the following:

```
def ChoiceBox(choice):

    choice_frame = Frame(win1, bg='black')
    choice_frame.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
    column = 0
    if choice == "Fixed":
        choice_frame.grid_forget()      
        tkMessageBox.showinfo("Message", "Fixed.")
    elif choice == "List":
        i = [0, 1, 2, 3]
        for i in i:
            choice_title = Label(choice_frame, text='Value %g'% float(i+1), bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            choice_title.grid(row=0, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)

            box = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="ew", padx=1, pady=1)
    elif choice == "Between" or "Bigger":
        i = [0, 1]
    choice_title1 = Label(choice_frame, text='Min Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        choice_title1.grid(row=0, column=column, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        choice_title2 = Label(choice_frame, text='Max Value', bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
        choice_title2.grid(row=0, column=column+1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
        for i in i:
            box = Entry(choice_frame, bg='white', borderwidth=0, width=0)
            box.grid(row=1, column=column+i, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
```

I am currently getting the two separate tables but the choice_frame 'table' is not the same size as the other one. I therefore wish to either make this table a part of the frame for the first table (and then somehow be able to delete just this section), which I have already made work. The other frame is frame_table (the one in which I made the original table) and would like to be joining with this frame.

Otherwise I wish to keep it like a separate table but I can't make it disappear on selecting 'Fixed'. This code is purely the command for the OptionMenu I have previously created. Any help given I would greatly appreciate! Thank you.

UPDATE: Now require to obtain an individual frame for each row depending on the choice (see image below). I'm hugely struggling on this!

[image]

Comment: I'm confused what you're trying to do here.  what is the other frame you're talking about (`win1` maybe?)?  Every time you call this function, you're creating a new frame.  I think you want to hold a reference to the created frame and then decide if you should put it on the grid, or `grid_forget` it (or possibly destroy the old `Frame` and then replace it with a new one)...

Comment: The other frame is one in which I made the table in and is not the root frame.I think I'm getting confused when I wish to do several different things depending on the choice.

Comment: I'm looking to get the values from these Entry widgets later on when a button is pressed but am mixing up all my definitions in doing so. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a slightly better example (compared to the one I had previously):

```
import Tkinter as tk

class TableWithFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self,master=None,*args,**kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,master,*args,**kwargs)
        self.table=tk.Frame(self)
        self.table.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.optionmenu=None
        self.option=tk.StringVar()

        self.frames={}
        self.options=[]
        self.current_choice=None

        self.add_optionmenu()
        self.option.trace("w",self.option_changed)


    def add_option(self,option_string,frame):
        self.options.append(option_string)
        if(self.optionmenu is not None):
            self.optionmenu.destroy()
        self.add_optionmenu()
        self.frames[option_string]=frame

    def add_optionmenu(self):
        if(self.optionmenu is not None):
            self.optionmenu.destroy()

        if(self.options):
            self.optionmenu=tk.OptionMenu(self,self.option,*self.options)
            self.optionmenu.grid(row=1,column=0)

    def option_changed(self,*args):
        choice=self.option.get()
        if(self.current_choice is not None):
            self.current_choice.grid_forget()
        self.current_choice=self.frames[choice]
        self.current_choice.grid(row=0,column=1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    def populate_table(table):
        """ junk data """
        for j in range(3):
            for i in range(10):
                l=tk.Label(table,text='%d'%(i*j))
                l.grid(row=j,column=i)


    def create_opt_frames(TWF):
        #Fixed Frame
        F=tk.Frame(TWF)
        F.boxes={}
        TWF.add_option('Fixed',F)

        #List Frame
        F=tk.Frame(TWF)
        F.boxes={}
        for i in (1,2,3,4):
            choice_title = tk.Label(F, text='Value %g'% float(i+1))
            choice_title.grid(row=0, column=i, sticky="news")
            box = tk.Entry(F, bg='white')
            box.grid(row=1, column=i, sticky="ew")
            F.boxes[i]=box

        TWF.add_option('List',F)

        #Bigger and Between Frame
        F=tk.Frame(TWF)
        F.boxes={}
        choice_title1 = tk.Label(F, text='Min Value')
        choice_title1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")
        choice_title2 = tk.Label(F, text='Max Value')
        choice_title2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="news")
        for i in (1,2):
            box = tk.Entry(F)
            box.grid(row=1, column=i-1, sticky="nsew", padx=1, pady=1)
            F.boxes[i]=box

        TWF.add_option('Between',F)
        TWF.add_option('Bigger',F)

    def print_boxes(TWF):
        """ Example of how to get info in Entry fields """
        if(TWF.current_choice is not None):
            for k,v in TWF.current_choice.boxes.items():
                print ("boxnum (%d) : value (%s)"%(k,v.get()))
        TWF.after(1000,lambda : print_boxes(TWF))

    root=tk.Tk()
    App=TableWithFrame(root)
    populate_table(App.table)
    create_opt_frames(App)
    print_boxes(App)
    App.grid(row=0,column=0)
    root.mainloop()
```

This works by creating a frame for each option in the option menu.  In reality, this could all be done from outside this class.  All that you do is add a frame for each option you want to have.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and this answer. I'm however wondering if it possible to show you my entire code in the chat as it's more of a question of integrating it all...I also haven't been using self etc. Do you think that would be possible?

Comment: @user2063 -- See updated code.  (especially the stuff in `if __name__ == '__main__'`)

Comment: I've come back to this answer as I've learnt a bit further on classes etc. I am however having difficulty incorporating a few of my other definitions as I don't understand how to work around 'if __name__ == '__main__'' and keep getting errors of 'self not defined'. Could you please explain what this line does and how I can continue to add in my other functions without this error? Thank you.

Comment: @user2063 -- when a python module is run (imported), the variable `__name__` gets assigned to the name of the module.  e.g. the code in `foo.py` would have `__name__ == "foo"`.  When you run your main script, (e.g., the file isn't imported), `__name__ == "__main__"`.  Basically, that test says, If I run this script without importing it via an import statement ...  As far as your `self` not defined errors, It's hard to say what's going on there.  Perhaps you forgot to add self as the first parameter to your methods?

Comment: I'd basically like to get rid of this line and be able to access all within the same class. I have two code files at the moment. One using the above system which works well but I'm stuck on adding in some other functions and reproducing the new frame when the optionmenu is changed but for each ROW. The other, I can import and create several rows but can't seem to integrate this code above. Is there any way you could help me as I'm sooo close with both files but not quite.

Comment: I have added in an image of briefly what I'm trying to get. An optionmenu is created for each row but then they need to show their individual option (not all 'list' at the same time). I also have a function which sets one option menu automatically to a value (if 'fixed' units = 'mm') but can't seem to incorporate that either into my code.

Comment: @user2063 -- At this point, using comments makes it too difficult to converge on a solution.  I would suggest you open a new question with your current difficulties.  That will give it greater visibility (other people may know a better answer than me), and allow you to have more than 500 characters to describe what you're having problems with at this point in your project.

Comment: I've posted two questions at this point but I'm really struggling either using your version and doing it row by row and adding in one or two others functions or trying to adapt my old code. The only way I can think people will understand is if I post my whole code but I can't do that.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to help me change and understand your code so to avoid using if __name__ == '__main__' please? I'm determined to understand it and make it work but I need to use it all under a class to use my other functions. I haven't had any replies to my other questions yet =(